# Calculating fields with same id but different status name

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, count, sum

I'm trying to create a view that will include a calculated field. This calculated field should give me a total by id for a single date.  Each item goes through a process.  Let's say a customer buys 3 books on a certain date, updates it to 4 but then decides to delete the order of 4 and keep it at 3.  So for the initial order it goes through 2-3 different statuses. When it's deleted or updated, it goes through 2 statuses.  The Quantity field remains the same and always positive.  How would I calculate to show a total?   See example:

```
| id    | item      | date        | Status     |  Quantity
| :---: | :---:     |:----------: | :----:     |  :------:
| 1     | Book      | 12-1-2020   | Initial    |    3
| 1     | Book      | 12-1-2020   | Processing |    3
| 1     | Book      | 12-1-2020   | Submitted  |    3
| 1     | Book      | 12-1-2020   | Updated    |    4        
| 1     | Book      | 12-1-2020   | Submitted  |    4   
| 1     | Book      | 12-1-2020   | Deleted    |    4
| 1     | Book      | 12-1-2020   | Submitted  |    4
| 5     | Magazine  | 12-3-2020   | Initial    |    10
| 5     | Magazine  | 12-3-2020   | Submitted  |    10
```

My query:

```
Select id, item, date, Status, Quantity, 
 Case when Quantity = 'Deleted' then Quantity * -1
     when Quantity = 'Initial' then Quantity * 0
     when Quantity = 'Updated' then Quantity * 0
     when Quantity = 'Processed' then Quantity * 0
     else Quantity end as CalculatedTotal from Table1
```

I thought this would work because each action has a Submitted status.  I was calculating only Submitted status and Deleted which is negative.  However if there's an Update status added, it throws off the calculation.

What I get with my query:

```
| id    | item      | date        | Status    |  Quantity  | CalculatedTotal
| :---: | :---:     |:----------: | :----:    |  :------:  | :-------------:
| 1     | Book      | 12-1-2020   | Initial   |    3       |   0
| 1     | Book      | 12-1-2020   | Processing|    3       |   0
| 1     | Book      | 12-1-2020   | Submitted |    3       |   3
| 1     | Book      | 12-1-2020   | Updated   |    4       |   0
| 1     | Book      | 12-1-2020   | Submitted |    4       |   4
| 1     | Book      | 12-1-2020   | Deleted   |    4       |  -4
| 1     | Book      | 12-1-2020   | Submitted |    4       |   4
| 5     | Magazine  | 12-3-2020   | Initial   |    10      |   0
| 5     | Magazine  | 12-3-2020   | Submitted |    10      |  10
```

id 1 on 12/1/2020 should total to 3 instead it's a total of 7.  id 5 on 12/3/2020 should be 10 which is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a window sum:

```
select t.*,
    sum(
        case  
            when quantity = 'Deleted' then -quantity
            when quantity in ('Initial', 'Updated', 'Processed' then 0
            else quantity
        end
    ) over(partition by id, date) as calculatedtotal
from mytable t
```

This computes the total for each id/date tuple, and assigns it to each and ever row in the partition. If you want a value that changes on every row, then you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows for each tupe; assuming `ordering_id`, you would change the `over()` clause of the window function to:

```
over(partition by id, date order by ordering_id)
```

Comment: I'll try this solution and see what it gives me.